# Linear Model: Why is my R² positive while my abline shows negative trend?

Tags: r, linear-model

This easy model is plotted with:

```
Polyommatus_icarus <- summary(lm(dat_hx$Jahr ~ dat_hx$Polyommatus_icarus)) 
r2 = Polyommatus_icarus$adj.r.squared
Polyommatus_icarus$coefficients
my.p = Polyommatus_icarus$coefficients[2,4]

plot(Polyommatus_icarus ~ Jahr, data=dat_hx,
     xlab = "Jahr", ylab = "Individuen",
     main = "Korrelationskoeffizient von Polyommatus_icarus")
abline(lm(Polyommatus_icarus ~ Jahr, data=dat_hx))
mylabel = bquote(italic(R)^2 == .(format(r2, digits = 3)))
text(x = 19, y = 2.5, labels = mylabel)

rp = vector('expression',2)
rp[1] = substitute(expression(italic(R)^2 == MYVALUE), 
                   list(MYVALUE = format(r2,dig=3)))[2]
rp[2] = substitute(expression(italic(p) == MYOTHERVALUE), 
                   list(MYOTHERVALUE = format(my.p, digits = 2)))[2]
legend('topright', legend = rp, bty = 'n')
rm(my.p)
```

Can someone explain why the R² isn't negative ?
Because it should be since the individual-count is decreasing over the years.

(Eli5 appreciated, because I didnt code statistics for a long time)

At gis.stackexchange someone mentioned that I used an inappropriate model, is this the problem?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Yes, the model is a problem: the points appear to follow an exponential-like trend, rather than a linear one, and they vary from this trend in a *heteroscedastic* way: the variation decreases as time increases.  These characteristics suggest better models, but choosing a good one also depends on what the data represent and what you are trying to accomplish.  You ought to consider asking a question that includes such information rather than asking what might have gone wrong with this flawed approach.

Comment: The correlation is negative, but its square won't be.

Answer (score 2):

R2 is a number that describes the variation accounted, it can't be negative. You must have confused it with correlation which can be negative.

Comment: So my model is valid?

Comment: @user2999399 I don't know. Your R2 is not very high, depends on your requirement, it can be good or bad. Your correlation is negative, which might make sense depend on the context.

Comment: The main confusion here is easily answered, but your model isn't obviously sensible. It implies negative values will be reached about 2016 (does that make sense?) and also seems to miss curvature in the data. I don't know what it shows scientifically.

Comment: it's just a trend, the correlation between some butterflies from 2001 to 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm.   It's R. Squared.  When you square a number, you get a positive number.

Comment: I always thought that R^2 was defined as $ (1 -\frac{sqErr}{Var}) $ where sqErr is the sum of squares of the residuals and Var is variance (also a sum of squares),  so apriori, it's not positive and hence, it's not a square. The fact that $ sqErr \leq Var $ follows from the math of OLS.  Random choices of values for the coefficients of the a model of the data as linear in the predictors could lead to 'R^2' values that are negative.  Am I saying something wrong ?

Comment: @aginensky If the squared error (sum of squares of residuals) exceeds the variance, throw away your model and just use the raw data!

Comment: @Dilip I believe aginensky's point is that $R^2$ actually *can* be negative.  Only the special circumstances of this model--namely, that an intercept term is included--assures its non-negativity.  Thus, the logic of this answer is invalid.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure whether "Thus, the logic of this answer is invalid." is directed towards my _comment_ or Moderator Peter Flom's _answer_ but I stand by my claim than the model in use should be discarded. To try a better model instead (e.g. one that includes an intercept (as the OP's indeed does) instead of insisting that $\hat{Y}=aX+b$ is an _affine_ model and not a linear model at all) might be an improvement over my suggestion of just using the raw data, but it could also be than the correlation is indeed $0$ and so the better model does not help very much.

Comment: @ dilip Of course one would throw the model away as the model is always inferior to the  model $ y = \bar{y} $, which has $ R^2 = 0$ .  I am just making the point that $R^2 \geq 0$ is a function of the model being the OLS  model and not an intrinsic algebraic property of the definition .

Comment: I cannot follow you guys.